# Django static files not loading after serving files in cpanel using whitenoise

Tags: python, django

I tried serving my static files using whitenoise, but still not getting any of my css/js loading in my pages.

I ran collectstatic after enabling whitenoise and static folder was generated.

I tried using both

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

and django's ManifestStaticFilesStorage backend.

Here are my settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    'crispy_forms',

    'classroom',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_school.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_school.wsgi.application'
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/static'),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

This is how my project is structured

```
home
-->etc
-->thegradientboostmvp
---->classroom
---->django-app
---->public
       >static
          >admin
          >css
          >img
          >vendor
          >second
          >third
          >fourth
---->static
------>admin
------>css
------>img
------>second
           >css
           >js
           >img
------>third
           >css
           >js
           >img
------>fourth
           >img
           >js
           >css
---->templates
```

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ]Try this way

Comment: @bmons tried that, unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

in my case putting my `static` folder in `public_html` solved.